# Google analytics displays (not set) value custom dimensions

Tags: php, google-analytics

Google analytics displays (not set) value custom dimensions. The custom dimension scope is "User".
Code to sent custom dimension for example:

```
$analytics
->setTrackingId('UA-178289400-1')
->setClientId('2069519135.1601459156') //some google id
->setHitType('pageview')
->setDocumentTitle('php')
->setDocumentPath('/Test')
->setCustomDimension('Lead', 3);
$analytics->sendPageview();
```

Library I use is https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol

URI request example:

> https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-178289400-1&cid=2069519135.1601459156&t=pageview&dt=php&dp=%2FTest&cd3=Lead

No errors, code response is 200. But custom dimensions displays (not set) or true value for 1 day, not all time visitor existence. And more often when this is the first page view of a visitor of the day.
As I understand it, user scope should set the last value for this and all after sessions of the visitor

Can you help me pls? Whats my mistake?

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en